# APScheduler not triggering. Next run time is stuck in a past time

Tags: python, cron, python-datetime, apscheduler

I have the below code that I use with AsyncIOScheduler of APScheduler.
The scheduled job should run every 15 minutes (x:00, x:15, x:30 and x:45).

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(asctime)s]%(message)s', datefmt="%H:%M")
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@scheduler.scheduled_job('cron', minute="*/15")
async def scheduled_job1():
    logging.CRITICAL("Job 1 Ran!")

# Some async methods with Discord.py

scheduler.start()
```

The problem is this job never gets triggered. The critical logging is not done. APScheduler logs below lines when I run the script.

```
[14:16]Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[14:16]Added job "scheduled_job1" to job store "default"
```

But it never does any other logging even on the trigger times.

When I try to check the job with `print scheduler.get_jobs()[0]` the "next run" data of the output points to a past time. I guess the time of the first planned trigger.

Example output:
`scheduled_job1 (trigger: cron[minute='*/15'], next run at: 2023-07-29 14:15:00 UTC)`

The time of the system looks like correct when I check it with the `datetime` module.

I can't really figure out why the jobs don't get triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code: replace line `logging.CRITICAL("Job 1 Ran!")` with `logging.critical("Job 1 Ran!")`

`logging.CRITICAL` is a constant used to set logging levels.

`logging.critical()` is a method that sends a `critical` message to the log.

Your code is working on my machine. I've changed it a little bit (this version sends message every five minutes and added `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()`):

```py
import logging
import asyncio

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(asctime)s]%(message)s', datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
logging.getLogger('apscheduler').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@scheduler.scheduled_job('cron', minute="*/5")
async def scheduled_job1():
    logging.critical("Job 1 Ran!")

# Some async methods with Discord.py

scheduler.start()    

print(scheduler.get_jobs()[0])

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

Comment: Sadly, the code didn't even get to throw an error because there was no trigger. I am guessing it might be because of the discord.py module using the asyncio thread and creating an incompatibility.

I solved the problem by using BackgroundScheduler instead.